# How to order results randomly using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------+-------+
| id | color | numb  |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | red   | 1     |
| 2  | red   | 2     |
| 3  | red   | 3     |
| 4  | blue  | 1     |
| 5  | blue  | 2     |
| 6  | green | 1     |
| 7  | green | 2     |
| 8  | green | 3     |
| 9  | green | 4     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Now I want a different order for each request randomly *(dynamic order)*. For e.g here is the **query**:

```
select * from mytable where color = 'green' order by {?};
```

**First execution:**

```
// newtable
+----+-------+-------+
| 7  | green | 2     |
| 6  | green | 1     |
| 8  | green | 3     |
| 9  | green | 4     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

**Second execution:**

```
// newtable
+----+-------+-------+
| 9  | green | 4     |
| 8  | green | 3     |
| 6  | green | 1     |
| 7  | green | 2     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

And so on ..., There isn't any specific rule .. just randomly. Well, Is there any mysql function or any approach for doing that?

Comment: It is worth noting that using MySQL `rand` is very inefficient and will cause MySQL to load every row and then rearrange them so makes indexing pointless and causes a significant processing overhead. It would be better/faster/smoother to output the data in order and then randomise the order in the code such as with `PHP` randomising the output array of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `order by rand()`.  The `rand()` function produces a random value and is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
     SELECT * FROM mytable
     WHERE color = 'green'
     ORDER BY NEWID()
```

EDIT:

```
     ORDER BY RAND()
```

also works